# How can I use fgets in VS

Tags: c, debugging

I've been trying to run this code on VS2017. The code is compiling and running, but not in the way I want it too. So, I try to use the debugger and it says:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>   Program:
>
> File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\fgets.cpp
>
> Line:33
>
> Expression: stream.valid()

From past questions I understood that it may happen because of mishandling the opening of files, but I think that my code does take care of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(my relevant code):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, count_commands, PC_A, lastLine;
    int *PC = &PC_A;
    FILE *memin;
    FILE *memout;
    FILE *regout;
    FILE *trace;
    FILE *count;
    assert(argc == 6);
    *PC = 0;
    count_commands = 0;
    //allocationg memory for registers content
    char **regs = (char **)(malloc(sizeof(char *) * 16));
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        regs[i] = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(char) * 9));
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            regs[i][j] = '0';
        }
        regs[i][8] = '\0';
    }
    //allocationg memory for the memory image we have
    char **memory = (char **)(malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4096));
    for (i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
        memory[i] = (char *)(malloc(sizeof(char) * 9));
        memory[i][0] = '\0';
    }

    //load memin image into memory
    char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    memin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (memin != NULL) {
        perror(strerror(errno));
    }
    int j = 0;
    while ((line = fgets(line, 10, (FILE *)memin)) != NULL) {
        strcpy(memory[j], line);
        memory[j][8] = '\0';
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: `fgets(line, 10,...` and `malloc(sizeof(char) * 8)` .. see a problem? With numbers.

Comment: By cpprefernce.com, fgets reads at most count-1 chars OR eof OR newline char, whatever comes first. For that matter I could have written 1000, it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Do you know for sure what your file is containing? Well, we don't.

Comment: I do know. It's just 4096 lines of strings of length 8

Comment: String of length `8` needs `9` bytes of storage for null-termination.

Answer (score 0):

After opening the file, in OP's code there is this check:

```
if (memin != NULL) {
    perror(strerror(errno));
}
```

So, if the opening *succeeded* an error string is printed. In my implementation, it reports:

```
Success: Success
```

No action is taken if it *fails* to open the file.

When it comes to the actual reading of all the lines in the file, there are some other issues. A buffer (`char` array) named `line` of size **8** is dinamically allocated and passed to `fgets`:

```
while ((line = fgets(line, 10, (FILE *)memin)) != NULL) {
//                         ^^
```

Note that **10** is also passed, as size of the buffer, which is wrong, because it allows `fgets` to write out of the bounds of the allocated array.

Also, given OP's compiler is MSVC 2017, I assume this code is running on Windows, so chances are that in the file, the lines are terminated by a `"\r\n"` sequence, rather then a single `'\n'`. Even if OP is confident that each line is a 8 char string, `fgets` needs a buffer of *at least* size 8 + 3 (8 + '\r' + '\n' + '\0') to read them safely.

Consider how those suggestions are implemented in this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MEM_SIZE  1024u
#define LINE_SIZE  128u
#define STR_SIZE     8u

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Try to open the input file
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing file name in command line.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE *memin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (memin == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file [%s].\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // I'd use plain arrays to store the lines
    char memory[MEM_SIZE][STR_SIZE + 1] = {{'\0'}};
    char line[LINE_SIZE] = {'\0'};
    size_t count = 0;
    while ( count < MEM_SIZE && fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, memin) ) {
        size_t length = strcspn(line, "\r\n");
        if (length > STR_SIZE) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Warning, line too long: %zu.\n", count);
            length = STR_SIZE;
        }
        memcpy(memory[count], line, length);
        memory[count][STR_SIZE] = '\0';
        ++count;
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
        printf("[%s]\n", memory[i]);
    }
}
```